# How to overwrite source table azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to ADF. I have a pipeline which deletes all rows of any of the attributes are null. Schema : { Name, Value, Key}

I tried using a data flow with Alter Table and set both source and sink to be the same table but it always appends to the table instead of overwriting it which creates duplicate rows and the rows I want to delete still remain. Is there a way to overwrite the table.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your specific pipeline details. Also, asking for suggestions outside of what you've done... turns this into a broad question seeking alternate solutions for the Community to invent. I removed this request, accordingly.

Comment: That said: not sure how you are going to destroy the very table you are reading from (and really this smells like an anti-pattern, vs writing a new table, as a transform)

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that your table is SQL table**, I have tried to overwrite the source table after deleting the specific null values. It successfully deleted the records but **got the duplicate records** even after exploring various methods.

So, as an alternate you can try the below methods to achieve your requirement:

**By Creating new table and deleting old table:**

- This is my sample source table names `mytable`.
  [image]
- Alter transformation

  [image]
- Give new table in the **sink** and in **settings->post SQL scripts**. give the drop command to delete the source dataset. Now your sink table is your required table. `drop table [dbo].[mytable]`

  [image]
- Result table(named `newtable`) and old table.

  [image]

  Source table deleted.

   [image]

**Deleting null values from source table using script activity**

- Use script activity to delete the null values from source table.

  [image]

- Source table after execution.

  [image]